# Cannot implicitly convert 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Collections.Generic.List<string>>' to 'System...<string,string>'

Tags: c#

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {           
        Dictionary<string, string> questionDict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>(); //creating animal dict
        List<string> removeKeys = new List<string>(); //so I can remove the keys if need be
        questionDict.Add("Does it have whiskers?", "cat");
        questionDict.Add("Does it purr?", "cat");
        questionDict.Add("Does it bark?", "dog");
        while (true)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in questionDict)//checks for each value of kvp in questionDict
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Computer: {0}", kvp.Key); //prints kvp, or in this instance, the question
                string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
                if (userInput.ToLower() == "yes") //if yes THEN
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("VAL: {0}", kvp.Value); //writes the value
                }
                else
                {
                    removeKeys.Add(kvp.Key); //adds the wrong animals to the removeKeys list
                }
            }
            foreach(string rKey in removeKeys)
            {
                questionDict.Remove(rKey); //removes all the values of rKey in removeKeys from questionDict
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();` is giving me the error. Any help? I'm trying to make my dictionary have more than one value per key, which I am told can only be achieved through `List<string>`.

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand? Look at both sides of that line.

Comment: Well, you just said earlier on that same line you wanted a <string, string> dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

Change your declaration to:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> questionDict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

The generic arguments of the variable being assigned to have to match those of what you are instantiating. The type also has to match of course (which it already did). Please make sure to make this correction to *other* applicable pieces of your code, like your `foreach` loop definition.

**Note**, if you like var (and even if you don't, this is one of the better places it can be used) you can just write:

```
var questionDict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

Which is much shorter, and harder to mess up!

Comment: Yes, that would make this error harder to run into (even if I normally don't use var :) )

Comment: Well I'm a big fan of it, but even if you aren't you have to admit that this is one of the least controversial ways you could use it.

Comment: Totally agree with that!

Comment: The rest of his code wants the values in the dictionary to be a single string though.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot Yes, this change needs to propagate to the rest of his code.

Comment: My point is that *nothing* in his code actually needs the value of the dictionary to be a `List<string>`. He's really just working with tuples of two strings.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot We don't know that (at least from this question). He just says "I'm trying to make my dictionary have more than one value per key". A `List` is certainly a reasonable way to achieve that.